# Redirection URL for Microsoft Live OAuth2 API

Tags: oauth-2.0, onedrive

I have multiple domain names, but all of that resolves to the same IP.
eg. x.mysite.com and y.mysite.com for my different customers.
    at the same time app.mysite.com also points to the same IP, server etc.

With Google OAuth2 API, in the redirect_url I am able to specify "app.mysite.com" and everything works.

But on MS Live, I have to hand-edit the API settings to add a new domain z.mysite.com/oauth2callback.

Is there a way around this?

In short, is there a way to specify a generic domain for OAuth from app.mysite.com in MS Live API settings?

This feature is available in GoogleDrive, Dropbox etc.

Update : OAuth2 callback works with the generic domain on Live. And I am able to get a valid access_token, and then successfully make API calls with that access_token. What doesn't work is the file picker JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, OneDrive doesn't support this feature that is supported by most of the other providers.
Please vote for this feature to be added.

http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/7815039-add-support-multiple-domains-in-redirect-uri-witho